# Mejorar consulta SQL Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, mvc

Estoy queriendo mejorar el código que busca en la base de datos información que luego muestro en una tabla en la vista. 
En la tabla se muestran los equipos de una empresa (PC, monitores, impresoras, etc).En la misma se puede buscar por nº de equipamiento, puesto, usuario, area, IP o por TIPO de equipamiento.

Quiero buscar la manera de simplificar el cógido debido a que es engorroso buscar errores y agregar un nuevo filtro también

Adjunto la mitad del código (el if principal se encarga de si se seleccionó un "tipo" de equipamiento o no"

Aguardo alguna respuesta, gracias!

[image: La imagen muestra la tabla que está en la vista, con sus respectivos filtros]

```
if ($tipo == 0) {
        //La busqueda por puesto y area son vacias
        if ($puesto == null and $area == null){
            //La busqueda por usuario es vacia
            if($usuario == null){
                $equipamientos = DB::table('equipamientos')
                ->leftjoin('relaciones', function($join){
                    $join->on('equipamientos.id_e','relaciones.equipamiento');
                    $join->on('relaciones.estado','=',DB::raw("1"));
                })
                ->leftjoin('puestos', function($join) use ($puesto){
                    $join->on('puestos.id_puesto','relaciones.puesto')
                    ->where('puestos.desc_puesto','LIKE', "%$puesto%");
                })
                ->leftjoin('personas','puestos.persona','personas.id_p')
                ->leftjoin('area','puestos.area','area.id_a')
                ->where(function($q) use ($ip) {
                  $q->where('equipamientos.ip', 'LIKE', "%$ip%")
                  ->orWhere('equipamientos.ip', '=', null);
              })
                ->where('equipamientos.id_e', 'LIKE', "%$equipo%")
                ->select('equipamientos.id_e as id_equipamiento','puestos.desc_puesto as puesto' , 'equipamientos.ip as ip','area.nombre_a as area', 'personas.nombre_p as nombre', 'personas.apellido as apellido', 'relaciones.id_r as relacion')
                ->orderBy('id_equipamiento','asc')
                ->paginate(20);
            }
                //La busqueda por usuario no es vacia
            else{
                $equipamientos = DB::table('equipamientos')
                ->leftjoin('relaciones', function($join){
                    $join->on('equipamientos.id_e','relaciones.equipamiento');
                    $join->on('relaciones.estado','=',DB::raw("1"));
                })
                ->leftjoin('puestos', function($join) use ($puesto){
                    $join->on('puestos.id_puesto','relaciones.puesto')
                    ->where('puestos.desc_puesto','LIKE', "%$puesto%");
                })
                ->leftjoin('personas','puestos.persona','personas.id_p')
                ->leftjoin('area','puestos.area','area.id_a')
                ->where(function($q) use ($ip) {
                  $q->where('equipamientos.ip', 'LIKE', "%$ip%")
                  ->orWhere('equipamientos.ip', '=', null);
              })
                ->where(function($q) use ($usuario) {
                  $q->where('personas.nombre_p', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%")
                  ->orWhere('personas.apellido', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%");
              })
                ->where('equipamientos.id_e', 'LIKE', "%$equipo%")
                ->select('equipamientos.id_e as id_equipamiento','puestos.desc_puesto as puesto' , 'equipamientos.ip as ip','area.nombre_a as area', 'personas.nombre_p as nombre', 'personas.apellido as apellido','relaciones.id_r as relacion')
                ->orderBy('id_equipamiento','asc')
                ->paginate(20);
            }    
        }
        //Si se aplica algun filtro de busqueda sin seleccionar tipo de equipamiento   
        else{
            $equipamientos = DB::table('equipamientos')
            ->leftjoin('relaciones', function($join){
                $join->on('equipamientos.id_e','relaciones.equipamiento');
                $join->on('relaciones.estado','=',DB::raw("1"));
            })
            ->leftjoin('puestos', function($join) use ($puesto){
                $join->on('puestos.id_puesto','relaciones.puesto')
                ->where('puestos.desc_puesto','LIKE', "%$puesto%");
            })
            ->leftjoin('personas','puestos.persona','personas.id_p')
            ->leftjoin('area','puestos.area','area.id_a')
            ->where(function($q) use ($ip) {
              $q->where('equipamientos.ip', 'LIKE', "%$ip%")
              ->orWhere('equipamientos.ip', '=', null);
          })
            ->where('equipamientos.id_e', 'LIKE', "%$equipo%")
            ->where('area.nombre_a', 'LIKE', "%$area%")
            ->select('equipamientos.id_e as id_equipamiento','puestos.desc_puesto as puesto' , 'equipamientos.ip as ip','area.nombre_a as area', 'personas.nombre_p as nombre', 'personas.apellido as apellido','relaciones.id_r as relacion')
            ->orderBy('id_equipamiento','asc')
            ->paginate(20);
        }
    }
    return view ('equipamiento.inicio', array('equipamientos'=>$equipamientos, 'equipo'=>$equipo,'puesto'=>$puesto,'ip'=>$ip,'tipo_equipamiento'=>$tipo_equipamiento, 'usuario'=>$usuario, 'area'=>$area, 'acceso'=>$acceso));
}
```

Comment: Si creas un Stored procedure en la Base de Datos?

Comment: ¿Tienes los modelos creados?

Answer (score 0):

Traté de entender el problema lo más que pude, así quedó la consulta:

```
    if ($tipo == 0) {
        $equipamientos = DB::table('equipamientos')
            ->leftjoin('relaciones', function($join){
                $join->on('equipamientos.id_e','relaciones.equipamiento');
                $join->on('relaciones.estado','=',DB::raw("1"));
            })
            ->leftjoin('puestos', function($join) use ($puesto){
                $join->on('puestos.id_puesto','relaciones.puesto')
                ->where('puestos.desc_puesto','LIKE', "%$puesto%");
            })
            ->leftjoin('personas','puestos.persona','personas.id_p')
            ->leftjoin('area','puestos.area','area.id_a')
            ->where(function($q) use ($ip) {
              $q->where('equipamientos.ip', 'LIKE', "%$ip%")
              ->orWhere('equipamientos.ip', '=', null);
            })
            ->where('equipamientos.id_e', 'LIKE', "%$equipo%");
        if ($puesto != null){
            //La busqueda por puesto
        }
        if($usuario != null)
            $equipamientos
                ->where(function($q) use ($usuario) {
                  $q->where('personas.nombre_p', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%")
                  ->orWhere('personas.apellido', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%");
                });
        if ($area != null)
            $equipamientos->where('area.nombre_a', 'LIKE', "%$area%")

        $equipamientos
            ->select('equipamientos.id_e as id_equipamiento','puestos.desc_puesto as puesto' , 'equipamientos.ip as ip','area.nombre_a as area', 'personas.nombre_p as nombre', 'personas.apellido as apellido', 'relaciones.id_r as relacion')
            ->orderBy('id_equipamiento','asc')
            ->paginate(20);
    }
    return view ('equipamiento.inicio', array('equipamientos'=>$equipamientos, 'equipo'=>$equipo,'puesto'=>$puesto,'ip'=>$ip,'tipo_equipamiento'=>$tipo_equipamiento, 'usuario'=>$usuario, 'area'=>$area, 'acceso'=>$acceso));
}
```

Te dejo un enlace por si quieres más información sobre [consultas en Eloquent](https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db).

Comment: La consulta no devuelve datos...

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco la respuesta.
Edité el código siguiendo tu ejemplo pero la consulta no me devuelve datos.
El código quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($tipo == 0) {
        $equipamientos = DB::table('equipamientos')
        ->leftjoin('relaciones', function($join){
            $join->on('equipamientos.id_e','relaciones.equipamiento');
            $join->on('relaciones.estado','=',DB::raw("1"));
        })
        ->leftjoin('puestos', function($join) use ($puesto){
            $join->on('puestos.id_puesto','relaciones.puesto')
            ->where('puestos.desc_puesto','LIKE', "%$puesto%");
        })
        ->leftjoin('personas','puestos.persona','personas.id_p')
        ->leftjoin('area','puestos.area','area.id_a')
        ->where(function($q) use ($ip) {
          $q->where('equipamientos.ip', 'LIKE', "%$ip%")
          ;
      })
        ->where('equipamientos.id_e', 'LIKE', "%$equipo%");
        if($usuario != null){
            $equipamientos->where(function($q) use ($usuario) {
              $q->where('personas.nombre_p', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%")
              ->orWhere('personas.apellido', 'LIKE', "%$usuario%");
          });
        }
        if($area != null){
            $equipamientos->where('area.nombre_a', 'LIKE', "%$area%");            
        }                 
        $equipamientos->select('equipamientos.id_e as id_equipamiento','puestos.desc_puesto as puesto' , 'equipamientos.ip as ip','area.nombre_a as area', 'personas.nombre_p as nombre', 'personas.apellido as apellido','relaciones.id_r as relacion', 'equipamientos.obs as obs')
        ->orderBy('id_equipamiento','asc')
        ->paginate(20);
    }
```